# How to replace text in a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

This is my code, I want to replace the word "here" with "potato" in the simplest way.

```
Private Sub btnreplace_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles btnreplace.Click
    txttyping.Text.Replace("here", "potato")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Strings (text) are immutable.**  This means they cannot be changed directly, to alter one, a *new string* is created/returned.

```
txttyping.Text = txttyping.Text.Replace("here", "potato)
```

`Replace()` returns a new string which needs to be assigned.  This is true for **all** the `String` methods which change the string: `ToLower()`, `ToUpper()`, `Remove()`, PadLeft(), `Copy()`, `Remove()`, `TrimEnd()`.

See [MSDN String Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx):

> A String object is called immutable (read-only), because its value cannot be modified after it has been created. Methods that appear to modify a String object actually return a new String object that contains the modification.

Answer (score 0):

since its a particular word you can use simple text replacement other than using regex.replace()

try this

```
txttyping.Text = Replace(txttyping.Text, "here", "potato")
```

here replace(sourcestring,findword,replaceword)