# VB.NET: Can't use the replace function inside a function

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem replacing a certain string inside another string using a function. For some reason, the final string is still the same. Here is my code:

```
Private Function RemoveSomeChars(ByVal song As String)
    Dim finalSong As String = song
    If finalSong.ToLower.Contains("official") Then
        finalSong.ToLower.Replace("official", "")
    End If
    Return finalSong
End Function
```

And I use it like this:

```
MsgBox(RemoveSomeChars(currentSong))
```

Comment: [.Replace() is a function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20234795) returning a new string.  You should also turn on Option Strict

Comment: "thanks" on SO would be to upvote the linked answer.  The answer duplicated here too since it points out the possible issue with `.ToLower()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452) indicated in the comments; [String.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#Anchor_3) is a function that won't modify the underlying string but rather return a new string. In your case, you'd want to use it like this

```
finalSong = finalSong.ToLower.Replace("official", "")
```

[String.ToLower()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) will behave in much of the same way.

As a final note *(this may or may not be important to you but)* I'd like to point out that if your `if` block is entered then `finalSong` will be converted to all-lowercase whereas it'll be unchanged in the event that the `if` block is skipped.